# How to implement abstract method in non abstract , non inherited class in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

Hi I want to implement an abstract method in non abstract and non derived class   In inherited class (derived class) I can easily override method but I want to know is it possible to do so in non derived class.
I am pasting a part of code for the understanding
In the code I need to implement getAction() method in ActionBaseTester clas

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AbstractClassIssue.cs
{
    public abstract class ActionBase
    {
        public abstract bool getAction(ActionBase act);
    }

    public class ActionBaseDerived : ActionBase
    {
        public override bool getAction(ActionBase act)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    class ActionBaseTester
    {
        //How to implement getAction method in non abstract non inherited class
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: You can"t implement a method from an Interface or an Abstract class without inheriting the interface / class you want to implement... Simple as that.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The whole point of having an abstract method is that you can use the class as an interface contract - so why would you want someone to implement that contract without specifying that it does.

Comment: Answers to this question will only be useful if you explain why you do not want to inherit and how you want to call/invoke the method.

Comment: "I need to implement getAction() method in ActionBaseTester clas" Who told you this absurd requirement?

Answer (score 0):

- You have to inherit **ActionBaseTester** class from **ActionBase**.
- You have to write the method with **override** directive in class **ActionBaseTester**

Answer (score 0):

You already implemented the abstract method `getAction` from your abstract base-class `ActionBase` by writing `public override bool getAction(ActionBase act)`. That´s the point of abstract classes: providing functionality but leaving the implementation to their deriving classes. Now you may call this method within your Main-method via the following code:

```
ActionBase @base = new ActionBaseDerived();
@base.getAction(yourAction);
```